# RabbitMQ Worker Crash Issue

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, worker

My NodeJS rabbitmq worker often throwing exceptions like below:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

    Error: PRECONDITION_FAILED - unknown delivery tag 3
        at Queue._onMethod (/Users/Rana/WebstormProjects/TS/ts-worker/node_modules/amqp/amqp.js:1720:15)
        at Queue.Channel._onChannelMethod (/Users/Rana/WebstormProjects/TS/ts-worker/node_modules/amqp/amqp.js:1365:14)
        at Connection._onMethod (/Users/Rana/WebstormProjects/TS/ts-worker/node_modules/amqp/amqp.js:922:28)
        at AMQPParser.parser.onMethod (/Users/Rana/WebstormProjects/TS/ts-worker/node_modules/amqp/amqp.js:797:12)
        at AMQPParser._parseMethodFrame (/Users/Rana/WebstormProjects/TS/ts-worker/node_modules/amqp/amqp.js:442:10)
        at frameEnd (/Users/Rana/WebstormProjects/TS/ts-worker/node_modules/amqp/amqp.js:187:16)
        at frame (/Users/Rana/WebstormProjects/TS/ts-worker/node_modules/amqp/amqp.js:172:14)
        at AMQPParser.header [as parse] (/Users/Rana/WebstormProjects/TS/ts-worker/node_modules/amqp/amqp.js:159:14)
        at AMQPParser.execute (/Users/Rana/WebstormProjects/TS/ts-worker/node_modules/amqp/amqp.js:231:21)
        at Connection.<anonymous> (/Users/Rana/WebstormProjects/TS/ts-worker/node_modules/amqp/amqp.js:837:12)
        at Connection.emit (events.js:95:17)
        at Connection.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:765:14)
        at Connection.emit (events.js:92:17)
        at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:427:10)
        at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:423:5)
        at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:166:9)
        at Connection.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:128:10)
```

My worker code is something like below:

```
    connection.queue('task-queue-name', {autoDelete: false, durable: true}, function(queue){
       queue.subscribe({ack: true, prefetchCount: 1}, function(params){
               //custom code
               queue.shift();
      });
  });
```

Does anyone have any clue what I might be missing that is causing the issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are (at least) two reasons I can think of why this could happen:

- you're calling `queue.shift()` for the same message multiple times
- if you have multiple listeners on the same queue from within the same Node process

Instead of using `shift`, you can acknowledge the messages separately:

```
queue.subscribe({ OPTS }, function (message, headers, deliveryInfo, messageObject) {
  messageObject.acknowledge(false);
  // or: messageObject.reject(true|false);
});
```

See [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amqp#queue-subscribe-options-listener) and also [this issue](https://github.com/postwait/node-amqp/issues/356).